# Struct as Output of a Function

Tags: c, struct, function-declaration

I wrote this code but when try to compile it, it returns thid error:

```
:24:8: error: conflicting types for ‘safe_syscall’
:19:10: note: previous implicit declaration of ‘safe_syscall’ was here
```

I specified the number of lines.

```
typedef struct syscall ditem;

void safe_syscall_set (vmi_instance_t vmi)
{
    ditem *head,*tmp = NULL;
    char *name;
    int num;
    FILE * fp;
    fp = fopen ("syscall.list", "r");//file including syscall names and numbers in format "name number"
    //read file of syscalls and numbers
    while(fscanf(fp, "%s %d",name, &num)!= EOF);
    {
        tmp = head;
/* 19 */
        head = safe_syscall(name,num,tmp,vmi);  
    }
    return;
}

/* 24 */
ditem *safe_syscall (char *syscall,int num,ditem *head,vmi_instance_t vmi)
{
    uint64_t *sys_call_table = 0xffffffff816003e0;
    uint64_t *memory = (uint64_t *) malloc(sizeof(*sys_call_table));

    char *path = "/home/ossl5/sysmap";//hardcoded
    FILE *fp;
    fp=fopen(path,"r");
    if(!fp)
    {  
        printf("ERROR CAN NOT OPEN SYSTEM.MAP FILE\n");
        goto exit;
    }
    curr = (ditem *)malloc(sizeof(ditem));
    curr->num = num;
    curr->next  = head;//new nodes are being added to head of the list
    head = curr;
    curr->sys_name = syscall;
    //Calculating syscall handler size
    curr->size  = sys_routine_size(fp,syscall,num); 
exit:
     return head;
}
```

I guess something is wrong with struct as output.This struct is a linked list and every time by calling `safe_syscall` function, new node is added to head of the list and the new head is returned by this function.

Comment: what is `24` here `24 ditem *safe_sys`

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan A syntax error.

Comment: I think the 19 and 24 are line numbers as indicted in the error messages. - probably should have put them in comments ;-)

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan: It's number of line.I only here added it and 19 on the other line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You haven't declared `safe_syscall()` so it is assumed to return an int. Try putting a declaration `ditem *safe_syscall (char *syscall,int num,ditem *head,vmi_instance_t vmi);` before the first call.